# How to add oEmbed support to my theme?

Tags: theme-development, themes, embed, oembed

oEmbed does not seem to work on my theme. I simply see the bare URL. I haven't been able to find instructions on how to implement it.

Thanks.

Comment: you shouldn't have to do anything to implement it, WordPress does it automatically via a filter on `the_content`. does your theme output content via `the_content`? is there any code in your theme removing filters on `the_content`?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give the URL. Please check if oEmbed url listed on the [internal WordPress whitelist](http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, got solved [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/oembed-not-working-for-a-specific-theme)

I just add the code from the last comment in my child themes functions.php, now embeds are working fine. Seems to be necessary because of automatically added paragraphs

The code for functions from the reference mentioned above:

```
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_autoembed_adjustments', 7 );
/**
 * Add a new line around paragraph links
 * @param string $content
 * @return string $content
 */
function my_autoembed_adjustments( $content ){
    $pattern = '|(?<!")(?<!"\s)(https?:\/\/[^\s"\[<]+)|im';    // your own pattern
    $to      = "<p>\n$1\n</p>";                          // your own pattern
    $content = preg_replace( $pattern, $to, $content );
    return $content;
}
```